# Creating Shapefile spatial index programmatically in .NET?

Tags: shapefile, spatial-index, dotspatial

I am creating a shapefile programmatically using DotSpatial using the following example syntax / pseudo code

```
FeatureSet features = new FeatureSet(DotSpatial.Topology.FeatureType.Polygon);
features.DataTable.Columns.Add( … // add column names and types

foreach (var featureData in featurDataCollection) //loop adding many features
{ 
    IGeometry feature = …  // create feature with attribution + geometry
    features.add(feature);
}

features.SaveAs(filepath, true);
```

I would like to ensure the output ShapeFile has a spatial index.  Is there a way to do this programmatically in .Net, (preferably using the DotSpatial libraries).

---

It would appear that in my naiveté that I have asked a more difficult question than I thought.  It seems that the [.sbn format is not as open as the other shapefile](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2012/06/gdalogr-using-shapefile-native-sbn.html) formats and there has been some [work on reverse engineering this](http://geospatialpython.com/2012/05/sbn-mystery-solved.html).  There also seems some mention of a [C# implementation that creates .sbn](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/10/your-chance-to-make-gis-history.html) files but I am still trying to figure this out.